# click event that fires when dragging an item (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-sortable

When I click on an item I can edit the field thanks to [bootstrap-editable](http://vitalets.github.com/bootstrap-editable/).
When I drag and drop the item I am able to change the position of the item thanks to [jquery.ui.sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists).

Using Google Chrome everything works fine.
By using Firefox `15.0.1` I have the following issue.

After I move the item, it appears the popup to edit the field.
I suppose this event is due to the event propagation.
I tried to fix it but with no success…

Here is my piece code:

```
    onSortReceive: function (e, ui) {
        this.$(ui.item[0]).trigger('drop', this.options.taskType);
        // TODO just on firefox there is a issue related to bootstrap-editable
        // it shows the popup even if there is e.stopPropagation() here
        // the only way to fix this issue is to re-render the view
        e.stopPropagation(); // it makes no difference 
        this.render(); // it fix the problem 
                       // but I want to avoid to re-render the view
    },
```

For the full code you can go on:
https://github.com/antonioJs/CoCoTask/pull/21/files

For the working version you can go on:
http://computerone.altervista.org/CoCoTask/ (the problem is just with firefox)

Any idea how to fix the problem?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Hi @tkone, yes I did but it does not work. thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is one working way i found. In your `taskItem.js` replace `onRender` with following code:

```
    onRender: function () {
        var sortInAction = false;
        this.$el.find('label').mouseup(function(e) {
          sortInAction = 'absolute' === $(e.target).closest('li').css('position');
        }).click(function(e) {
            if (sortInAction)
              e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }).editable({
            type: 'textarea',
            name: 'task-name',
            validate: this.editTaskName,
            template: '<textarea rows="3"></textarea>'
        });
    },
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should e.preventDefault() `mouseup` event, not `sortreceive` `jquery.ui` event. Maybe something like this would work (not tested):

```
'mouseup li': 'liMouseUp'

/* ... */

liMouseUp: function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('.ui-draggable-dragging')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Anyway: 1) $(e.target) = `label.editable` in both case, drag and drop and click 2) e.preventDefault() does not make difference. 3) by using `e.stopPropagation()` it stop to drop and it appears the popup to edit the field.

Comment: Try `$(e.currentTarget)` instead of `$(e.target)`

Comment: Yep, it doesn't work this way... Added another possible solution.